# ZF Sub Query Question

Tags: sql, zend-framework, subquery

I've got a user table with user_id as the primary key and a user_dates table which has user_date_id as the primary key, user_id which links to the user table and start_date and end_date fields.

I am trying to run a query to get a list of users and order them by the earliest date but only using the dates which haven't yet passed. Therefore, I am trying to run a sub query to get this date and then use it to order the users.

So far I have got the following to link the tables but im not sure how to add a sub query in ZF?

```
$oSelect = $this->getDbConnection()
  ->select()
  ->from(array('u' => 'users'), '*')
    ->joinInner(array('d' => 'user_dates')
    , 'u.user_id = d.user_id', array('start_date', 'end_date'))
```

The sub query is going to be something like:

```
SELECT start_date FROM user_dates d
WHERE d.user_id=u.user_id && start_date > NOW()
ORDER BY start_date ASC LIMIT 0,1
```

Thanks

So I could do the following:

```
$oSelect = $this->getDbConnection()
->select()
->from(array('u' => 'users'), '*')
->joinInner(array('d' => 'user_dates')
, 'u.user_id = d.user_id', array('start_date' =>
                          new Zend_Db_Expr('SELECT start_date FROM user_dates d WHERE d.user_id=u.user_id && start_date > NOW() ORDER BY start_date ASC LIMIT 0,1'), 'end_date;'))
```

I can't echo $oSelect because I havent got ZF on this machine but the query I am hoping to achieve is the following:

```
SELECT u . * , (

SELECT start_date
FROM dates d
WHERE d.user_id = u.user_id && end_date > NOW( )
ORDER BY start_date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 1
) AS date
FROM `users` u
INNER JOIN dates d ON u.user_id = d.user_id
WHERE end_date > NOW()
GROUP BY u.user_id
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

You're right, ignore the above, the query should be:

```
SELECT u. * , (

SELECT start_date
FROM dates d
WHERE d.user_id = u.user_id && end_date > NOW( )
ORDER BY start_date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 1
) AS date
FROM `users` u
GROUP BY u.user_id
HAVING date
ORDER BY date ASC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: suggestion: use $oSelect->__toString () to see exactly who the query looks.

Comment: Are you really sure of the SQL validity of your query? have you tried using HAVING? why do you join dates on the main query without using it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that subqueries work with Zend_Db_Select, although I am not 100% sure. The [docs](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_Db_Select.html#Zend_Db_Select%3a%3afrom%28%29) say that the param has to be :

```
array|string|Zend_Db_Expr $name
```

You may try to create a Zend_Db_Expr for your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery can be another Zend_Db_Select object, or you can use Zend_Db_Expr to wrap a string version if you are having problems.

They usually work as expected without any special work.

Comment: Please see my original post which I have now edited, does this seem right? I can't test it right now unfortunately.

Comment: I try to JOIN subqueries rather than stick them as expressions...  For now, do what Elzo said and echo $oSelect; to see what's being generated...